# Return type of [self class]

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to set the return type of a selector in objective-c to be the class itself?

For example, is it possible to do something like:

```
+ ([self class] *) selectorName;
```

So that given a super class such as:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {}
+ (MyClass *) instanceOfMyClass;
@end

@implementation MyClass 
+ (MyClass *) instanceOfMyClass {
  return [[[[self class] alloc] init] autorelease];
}
@end
```

The subclass does not need to cast the return value when doing things like:

```
@implementation MySubClass 
+ (MySubClass *) specialInstanceOfMySubClass {
  MySubClass *instance = [[self class] instanceOfMyClass];
  instance.special = YES;
  return instance;
}
@end
```

**In other words, im trying to expose the fact that the static method returns an instance of the class or its subclass. Otherwise, the subclass needs to be aware of information not provided in the interface.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing. There are basically two ways to type variables in Objective-C:

- *static*: like you already did: `ClassName *`
- *anonymous*: use the generic type `id` that can match any *object*

So in your case you could do a method declaration like this:

```
+ (id)instanceOfMyClass;
```

The **convention** is to return an instance of that class. Apple uses this convention in basically every class. If the result is different, you should write it in the documentation for this method. That's also the way Apple does this.

Another option would be to cast the result in you subclass' method.

```
MySubClass *instance = (MySubClass *)[[self class] instanceOfMyClass];
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to cast. Casting requires the subclass to have knowledge of the implementation of the super class; it's the same for using id (though with id it's less ambiguous). Casting bypasses strong typing.

Comment: Actually *I* don't know of any language that supports what you were asking for. May well be lack of my knowledge. However, the `id`-solution seems pretty okay to me...

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, i guess id's good enough. And since it's id and not MyClass *, then the subclass knows it's probably [self class].

Comment: better to use `instancetype` rather than `id` on methods like this. It's what Apple is changing to and is easier when subclassing

Answer (score 5):

Apple introduced the keyword [instancetype](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/) for exactly this reason.

You would use it as follows:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {}
+ (instancetype) instanceOfMyClass;
@end

@implementation MyClass 
+ (instancetype) instanceOfMyClass {
  return [[[[self class] alloc] init] autorelease];
}
@end
```