# In an objective c Protocol, how do I use the implementing class as a return value

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, protocols

Let's say I have a protocol, call it `Protocol A`. I want every class implementing A to have a method that has a return value of itself.

For example, class `Implementor` should have a method called "GetAnother" with a return value of Implementor.

Is this possible to force a class to do with Protocols? Because as far as I can see, you have to create methods with specific return values.

I don't want to return an `id` because I want people to be able to depend on the return value being a certain class.

Thanks!

Comment: as far as i know there's no straigthforward way of doing that... but i'd like to hear some thougts on this

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582504/return-type-of-self-class

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Template classes in Objective-C, but it doesn't exist. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043583/template-in-objective-c) for instance.